# How do i turn off automatic index view in Clion for arrays?

Tags: c++, ide, clion

[image]

I want to turn off the view for the index and look at the array normally

thanks!

I've checked my plug-ins, build and run configurations (data view), and checked the debugger itself. I'm not sure what else to do

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, from the *File* menu, open *Settings* → *Editor* → *Inlay Hints* → *Parameter names* → *C/C++*, and uncheck the box named "*Show hints for array indices*".

[image: Toggle parameter hints globally﻿]

See "[Toggle parameter hints globally](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/parameter-hints.html#hide)" on the CLion documentation page.